# Pourquoi les dialectes du français n'ont pas survécu en Europe ?

Tags: histoire, régionalismes, linguistique, accents-régionaux, dialectes

Certes, au XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle il existait dans l'espace francophone (France, Belgique, Suisse) des dialectes comme dans toutes les autres langues, dont notamment les groupes de langues d'oïl, langues d'oc et franco-provençal (qui n'avait pas de nom à l'époque où les gens l'utilisaient encore).

Cependant, il faut être réaliste, ces dialectes sont complètement éteints et même les paysans vivant dans les endroits les plus reculés ne parlent plus que le français standard depuis longtemps.

À l'inverse, en Allemagne, en Espagne, en Italie, et probablement dans beaucoup d'autres pays d’Europe, les dialectes sont réellement vivants à la campagne (et parfois même en ville), et ce malgré les tentatives de suppression des régimes fascistes.

Certes, il existe quelques différences mineures et certains mots qui diffèrent, mais il faut avouer que, en comparaison, le français est une langue qui ne varie que très peu en fonction de l'origine de ses locuteurs, à l'exception des Québécois.

Je suis convaincu que la raison de l'extinction de ces dialectes n'est pas politique, car elle a eu lieu en France comme en Suisse et en Belgique, et à l'inverse les dialectes de l'allemand et de l'italien sont très vivants en Suisse, y compris en ville.

Mon grand-père est né en 1918 dans une famille de paysans pauvres d'un village montagnard assez reculé, et il ne comprenait que des bribes de dialecte, et n'était pas capable de le parler. C'est donc un phénomène ancien, qui date déjà d'avant la Seconde Guerre mondiale.

Donc, pourquoi cette éradication totale des dialectes (seuls quelques mots isolés y ont subsisté)?

Comment: J'ai posé une question similaire sur linguistics.stackexchange.com http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8332/why-did-the-franco-proven%C3%A7al-language-decline-in-switzerland. Mais la vôtre est différente et je pense qu'il vaut mieux le demander ici à french.stackexchange.com.  C'est très mysterieux, ce phénomène.

Comment: Oui, et ta question est un peu différente, car elle vise le francoprovençal en particulier. Les réponses ne sont pas satisfaisantes car il n'y a pas que le suisse-allemand qui a survécu dans les dialetes des grandes langues européennes... Je pense que c'est vraiment propre au français d'être intrinciquement "antidialéctal". Pour nous les francophones il est *capital* de parler et d'écrire correctement le français alors que dans d'autres cultures ce n'est peut-être pas si important ?

Comment: Je ne crois pas qu'on puisse dire que le chti soit mort. C'est peut-être l'exception qui confirme la règle.

Comment: @mouviciel Le picard n’est plus que rarement parlé (je suis à cheval entre le Hainaut Occidentale et le Nord — en ville, certes — et je n’ai jamais entendu quiconque le parler hors Cabaret Wallon et autres) et est considéré comme en danger par l’UNESCO. Après, l’accent et les expressions, c’est autre chose…

Comment: J'imagine qu'il doit y avoir un ensemble de facteurs aussi variés que les différences entre ces pays et ces langues. Il faudrait comparer, incluant le politico-juridique. On pourrait observer la friction entre le droit de l'Union et le droit national. En France, on peut peut-être aborder le sujet sous l'angle des décisions du _Conseil constitutionnel_ dans le contexte de la _Corse_ ([article, voir II. A et 99-412 DC](http://www.conseil-constitutionnel.fr/conseil-constitutionnel/francais/nouveaux-cahiers-du-conseil/cahier-n-12/les-statuts-de-la-corse.52101.html)). C'est une perspective.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Tout ce qu’on vient de dire appelle la conclusion que, pour extirper
>   tous les préjugés, développer toutes les vérités, tous les talens,
>   toutes les vertus, fondre tous les citoyens dans la masse nationale,
>   simplifier le mécanisme & faciliter le jeu de la machine politique, il
>   faut identité de langage. Le temps amènera sans doute d’autres
>   réformes nécessaires dans le costume, les manières & les usages. Je ne
>   citerai que celui d’ôter le chapeau pour saluer, qui devroit être
>   remplacé par une forme moins gênante & plus expressive.

Abbé Grégoire (voir *infra*).

Il me semble que l'esprit révolutionnaire de 1789, universaliste et par là centralisateur, ne pouvait voir dans la disparition des patois, liés aux différents pays français, descendants des provinces sur lesquelles l'Ancien Régime s'appuyait, qu'un moyen d'exporter sa doctrine à la fois en rendant plus largement compréhensible puis dominatrice la langue dans laquelle elle s'exprimait (le français), mais aussi en détruisant ce qui faisait l'âme pérenne des provinces fidèles à leurs traditions, dont toutes celles, bien sûr, qui faisait l'Ancien Régime.

C'est très clairement l'idéologie révolutionnaire qui a produit cela depuis, exactement de la même façon qu'elle a produit le colonialisme ensuite : il s'agit d'ailleurs d'une seule et même chose.

Voir le *[Rapport sur la nécessité et les moyens d'anéantir les patois et d'universaliser l'usage de la langue française](http://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Rapport_sur_la_n%C3%A9cessit%C3%A9_et_les_moyens_d%E2%80%99an%C3%A9antir_les_patois_et_d%E2%80%99universaliser_l%E2%80%99usage_de_la_langue_fran%C3%A7aise)* de l'Abbé Grégoire, dont [Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapport_Gr%C3%A9goire) traite brièvement.

Par suite, il ne me semble pas douteux que l'esprit III<sup>e</sup> République est en droite ligne héritier de celui-là, tel qu'il n'a jamais cessé de s'incarner dans une tendance franc-maçonne dont Ferry ou plus près de nous Vincent Peillon sont les parfaits représentants.

Revenons pour finir à cette citation de Grégoire, tant en un paragraphe, tout y est dit : l'on voit bien comment l'esprit Procuste du curé trouve à se recycler parfaitement dans celui du pédagogue républicain. La dernière phrase, surtout, est frappante: l'idée que les hommes ne valent que comme des individus arrachés à leurs solidarités traditionnelles et libérés de toute détermination, jusque dans leur façon de manger ou de se saluer a ses échos jusqu'à nos jours à travers l'idéologie du cosmopolitisme, de l'homme nouveau communiste ou fasciste, ou aujourd'hui même, dans l'idéologie du genre.

Comment: J'ai failli moinser, mais je me suis retenu quand j'ai lu le passage sur la IIIe République. Je pense que si l'esprit révolutionnaire constitue l'origine de la disparition des patois, c'est bien l'esprit IIIe République qui a eu leur peau.

Answer (score 7):

Je pense que ça vient de la politique française du début du siècle qui a obligé, par la force, tout le monde à parler le français standard ; celui de Paris et de l'administration. Cette politique visait à uniformiser la France, car les patois étaient encore très présents dans chaque région.

C'est très déplorable d'ailleurs... Mais en Bretagne par exemple, on recommence à promouvoir le breton à l'école.

Comment: Et comment le gouvernement français aurait-il pu forcer les belges et les suisses à parler le français standard ? Quand au breton, c'est différent car ce n'est pas une langue voisine du français (idem pour le basque et l'alsacien)

Comment: A l'époque, le français avait beaucoup plus d'importance qu'aujourd'hui. Pour prendre la Belgique en exemple, le flamand n'était presque pas représenté au gouvernement à cette époque. Il était encore la langue de la diplomatie, et donc les pays francophones se calquaient sur la France qui était encore une puissance relativement grande, ou du moins une référence de la francophonie.

De plus, en Belgique il y avait le wallon qui n'était pas vraiment un patois français mais presque une langue à part entière, qui s'est éteinte petit à petit avec l'influence française.

Comment: D'ailleurs, l'influence française est encore très présente de nos jours. A Bruxelles, on n'entend presque plus de gens avec un accent fort belge ou parlant le "brusseleir", c'est-à-dire une sorte de mélange de français et de flamand, alors qu'il y a 30 ans encore c'était le cas. Tout le monde uniformise son accent sur l'accent français pour ne pas paraître "inférieur" ou "paysan". Cette problématique n'existe pas en Allemagne où chaque région est fière de son accent.

Comment: On peut ajouter qu'un des véhicules utilisés pour "franciser" les Français a été l'école où il était interdit de parler le "patois" ou plutôt la langue régionale.

Comment: Certes, mais ce n'est pas une raison. Les régimes faciste, nazi et franquiste n'ont pas réussi à eradiquer les dialectes respectivement en italie, en allemagne, et en espagne. Il n'y a rien eu de tel (en période de paix) ni en france, ni en belgique, ni en suisse, pourtant les patois sont morts et enterrés. Donc désolé mais cette réponse n'est pas vraiment suffisante. Mais peut-être est-ce juste culturel et qu'il n'y a pas vraiment de vraie réponse.

Comment: Pour prendre l'exemple de l'allemand, y-a-t'il eu une interdiction systématique des patois dans les écoles en Allemagne ? Je ne pense pas que ça ait été aussi violent qu'en France. De plus, la France est un pays centralisé alors que l'Allemagne est un pays divisé en "Länder" qui ont chacun leurs lois. La Bavière n'a donc jamais été contrainte par la Prusse de parler "Hochdeutsch". En Suisse, c'est l'inverse qu'on voit : le haut allemand était plus parlé jusqu'à la 2e guerre mondiale, puis le haut allemand n'a plus trop eu la cote... Le suisse allemand est donc revenu en force pour se démarquer

Comment: Encore une fois, ça ne joue pas. Depuis quand les enfants respectent-ils les règles si scrupuleusement à l'école ? Et il y a plein d'autres endroits où  parler le patois en dehors de l'école. Et je vois mal les suisses allemands étudier le dialecte de leurs grand-parents pour le re-parler artificiellement pour se distinguer des allemands... L'usage du dialecte a toujours été répendu, c'est juste qu'il a arrêté d'être mal considéré. Quand au fédéralisme, c'est vrai, et de même les cantons suisses n'ont jamais étés contraint par la françe de parler "bon français".

Comment: Je plussoie, car n'en déplaise à l'OP, il s'agit bel et bien de la bonne réponse: la raison est politique. Depuis quand les enfants respectent-ils les règles si scrupuleusement à l'école? Depuis qu'on leur tape sur les doigts, au sens propre, avec une règle (on parle du début du siècle). Ma grand-mère me racontait ça, elle parlait parfaitement le béarnais (patois occitan, donc "langue voisine du français"), mais comme beaucoup de gens de sa génération, ne l'a pas transmis à ses enfants (un traumatisme peut-être).

Answer (score 2):

La conversion linguistique, c'est aussi la diffusion de la communication en gros.  Les gens qui ne se déplacent que 100 bornes par exemple et y trouvent une autre langue/accent/dialecte : comment réagir et de quelle stratification sociale peut-on se faire comprendre ?

Tout a changé après la radio.  Puis le cinéma.  Puis la télé et tout surtout l'Internet, toutes les bandes vidéos et radios disponibles en ligne.  Les langues/dialectes/accents deviennent de moins en moins localisés quand tout le monde écoute la même langue "standardisée" ("le bon...") et beaucoup de monde cherche à comprendre cette idée de la même langue et à être plus facile à comprendre.  Ça arrive partout.  "L'extinction de ces dialectes" est malheureusement l'impératif catégorique de la communication.

Il y en a qui cherchent la préservation de la langue régionale et il y en a qui cherchent à ne plus se distinguer, ne pas se localiser quand ils parlent.  De la stratification ou la stigmatisation de la langue, les gens ont tendance à se faire comprendre et à la conformité.

La langue des enfants arrive en imitant leurs copains, pas leurs parents.  Autant en emporte le vent.

C'est la [conversion linguistique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_linguistique).